# React Frontend Error : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I am new to React, ASP.NET and Azure, so I guess I am having more of beginners problems. I am trying to develop a simple application with react frontend, asp.net web api backend and sql database. I decided to use the Azure sql database and also host both my frontend and backend on Azure. The problem I am having is that my frontend cannot fetch data to perform API endpoint such as login or signup. I have test the azure frontend hosting and it is working since I can see my frontend (see image attached) and I know that the backend deployment is also working since I can see the swagger index.html page (see image attached), but I am unable to login or signup or any endpoint as it just says failed to fetch and give the above error response. I have allowed all origin in the backend CORS settings and my backend is listening on http://localhost:5000 with endpoints such as /api/login e.t.c. What am I doing wrong for this error and how can I fix it? My development platform is visual studio. Also, I am using fetch and not axios.

[image: browser console tab]

[image: swagger page]

I have tried to add the frontend URL to the launchSetting.json applicationUrl which contains the https and http localhost port. I have also disable my windows defender firewall. I have seen several related article but none of what they suggest seems to work. Also I did not use any CORS setting in react as I was not sure it was needed and since I am only fetching the data using asp.net backend.